# Parsing using lxml and requests with python

Tags: python, html, xml, xpath, lxml

Recently I was trying to parse html table from web page using `lxml` and `requests`.

The python code runs like this:

```
>>> from lxml to html
>>> import requests
>>> page = requests.get('http://www.bigpaisa.com/candlestick-stock-screener-result/nse/bearish-evening-star-candlestick-pattern')
>>> tree = html.fromstring(page.text)'
```

Then I would like to parse the following repetitive data block using `lxml.xpath()` function to get lists:

```
<TR>
    <TD style="font-size: 11px;"><!-- <a href="/company-technical-details/<%=sr.getExchange()%>/<%=sr.getSymbol()%>/<%=sr.getName()%>" ><%= sr.getSymbol() %></a>  -->
                    AMTEKINDIA           </TD>
    <TD style="font-size: 11px; max-width: 135px;">AMTEK INDIA LIMITED</TD>
    <TD>                nse         </TD>
    <TD style="min-width: 60px; max-width: 60px;">02-01-2015</TD>
    <TD>78</TD>
    <TD>78.3</TD>
    <TD>72.25</TD>
    <TD>73.9</TD>
```

But unable to do so getting an error, e.g:

```
>>> symbol=tree.xpath('//TD[@style="font-size: 11px;"][@!-- [@a href="/company-t
echnical-details/[@%=sr.getExchange()%]/[@%=sr.getSymbol()%]/[@%=sr.getName()%]"
 ][@%= sr.getSymbol() %][@/a]  --]/text()')
```

giving Xpath evaluation error and

```
>>> prices=tree.xpath('//TD/text()')
```

returning list with no values.

Comment: `from lxml to html` is not valid Python. did you mean `from lxml import html`?

Answer (score 2):

The rows you are interested in are inside the `<table>` with the ID `sortable`.

```
from lxml import html

url = 'http://www.bigpaisa.com/candlestick-stock-screener-result/nse/bearish-%20evening-star-candlestick-pattern'
doc = html.parse(url)

# you can use XPath to select elements...
rows = doc.xpath("//table[@id = 'sortable']/tbody/tr")

# or, if you prefer, use CSS selectors instead...
rows = doc.cssselect("table#sortable tbody tr")

for tr in rows:
    # do something with each tr, for example
    tds = tr.cssselect("td")
    print tds[4].text
```

Note that you don't need the `requests` module at all.

Comment: It seems that the page declares a default XHTML namespace which you'd need to take into account in the path expression - if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: Not with the `lxml.html` parser it seems, I've tested that code and it works.

Comment: I see - the HTML parser simply ignores namespaces. ["Also note that the HTML parser is meant to parse HTML documents. For XHTML documents, use the XML parser, which is namespace aware."](http://lxml.de/parsing.html#parsing-html).

Comment: I think it's safe to use the HTML parser in this case. 95% of the web pages that claim to be XHTML are not, [this page is no exception](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bigpaisa.com%2Fcandlestick-stock-screener-result%2Fnse%2Fbearish-+evening-star-candlestick-pattern&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).

Comment: That's a good rationale - thanks for addressing it and + 1. Perhaps it would help to add a short caveat about this to your answer?

Comment: I wonder if that would improve the answer much, since it is so hypothetical. a) The website is not XML in the first place, b) the HTML parser ignores namespaces by default anyway and c) it doesn't make much difference for the use case. Last but not least, it's been mentioned in the comments for those who care.

Comment: Then leave it be, I agree, it doesn't matter much given the question above.